# ポリライン（線分、円弧）で線上の座標を一定間隔で取得したい

Tags: c#, ijcad

IJCAD 2020 STD Standalone
C#での開発を検討しております。

ポリライン（線分、円弧）で線上の座標を一定間隔で取得したいのですが、可能でしょうか？
Polyline
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

自己解決
PolylineのGetPointAtDist、GetSplitCurves、SetBulgeAtの組み合わせで実現できました。